# Write dataframe to excel with filter on

Tags: python, excel, pandas, filter

I am trying to write my dataframe to excel and would like to do it so that the filter option based on the first row in the dataframe is automatically selected when I open excel. I can obviously manually select filter in excel but was wondering if there is a way to code this in python?

Result would be that I open excel file containing dataframe and the filter option is already selected.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I've seen that there is an option via openpyxl but this seems to require knowing the references for the cells in excel over which you want to filter. This is not handy when the dataframe can differ in size so you will never be sure over which columns and rows you want to filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use openpyxl as you already tried to.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

data = [
    ["Fruit", "Quantity"],
    ["Kiwi", 3],
    ["Grape", 15],
    ["Apple", 3],
    ["Peach", 3],
]

for r in data:
    ws.append(r)

ws.auto_filter.ref = "A:B"

wb.save("filtered.xlsx")
```

The `ws.auto_filter.ref = "A:B"` sets the filter on the column name.
More information can be found [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Can xlsxwriter also do this? Already made all my exports with xlsxwriter. If not, is there a way to combine the 2? Would love to get an example. Thank you